# What is wrong with this class for getting connection from database pool

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I wrote a class to get connections from a database pool (**HikariCP**). I searched for error and it means that connection is closed. But, I am not able to figure out the problem. I am certain I did something wrong in the code, may be not closing the connection properly or whatever because after some time I start to get errors as below:

```
11:27:58.843 [http-apr-8080-exec-10] WARN  c.z.h.u.ConcurrentBag -
**Attempt to remove an object from the bag that does not exist: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@5f3145e5, created Oct 21, 11:27:12.734, last release 0ms ago, NOT_IN_USE 11:27:58.861 [http-apr-8080-exec-10] ERROR c.p.d.DAOConnectionFactory - Error while closing connection.** java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed   at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.ClosedConnection$1.invoke(ClosedConnection.java:51) ~[HikariCP-2.4.1.jar:na]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.clearWarnings(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]     at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.ConnectionProxy.close(ConnectionProxy.java:197) ~[HikariCP-2.4.1.jar:na]     at com.presence.dao.DAOConnectionFactory.closeConnection(DAOConnectionFactory.java:73)
**~[DAOConnectionFactory.class:na]   11:28:01.133 [http-apr-8080-exec-9] WARN  c.z.h.p.ConnectionProxy - HikariPool-0 - Connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@46fb3f92, created Oct 21, 11:27:12.781, last release 28ms ago, IN_USE marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(0) com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after statement closed.   at** sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]   at
```

Below is the class:

```
public class DAOConnectionFactory {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DAOConnectionFactory.class);
    private static final String databaseJNDI = "jdbc/presencedb";
    private static DataSource dataSource = null;
    private static Context context = null;
    private static Connection conn = null;

    private DAOConnectionFactory() {
        System.out.println("Initialized");
    }

    private static DataSource getDataSource() {
        if (dataSource != null) {
            return dataSource;
        }
        try {
            context = new InitialContext();

            if (context == null) {
                context = new InitialContext();
            }

            dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:comp/env/" + databaseJNDI);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            logger.error("Error while creating datasource.", e);
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    protected static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            conn = getDataSource().getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Error while getting database connection.", e);
        }
        return conn;
    }

    protected static void closeConnection(Connection connection, Statement statement, ResultSet resultSet) {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error while closing resultset.", e);
            }
        }
        if (statement != null) {
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error while closing statement.", e);
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error while closing connection.", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

hikaricp properties:

```
cachePrepStmts="true" 
defaultAutoCommit="true" 
description="Presence database." 
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory" 
global="jdbc/presencedb" 
jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://192.168.254.167/presence" 
maxWaitMillis="10000" maximumPoolSize="30" 
name="jdbc/presencedb" 
password="" 
prepStmtCacheSize="50" 
prepStmtCacheSqlLimit="512" 
removeAbandoned="true" 
removeAbandonedTimeout="300" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
idleTimeout="25200000"
maxLifetime="25200000"
username="root"
```

Add this is how I obtain the connection

```
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
connection = DAOConnectionFactory.getConnection();
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_UPDATE);

DAOConnectionFactory.closeConnection(connection, preparedStatement, null);
```

This happens always when I perform load testing otherwise for few random queries I have not noticed this.
*HikariCP version is 2.4.1.*

Comment: Illegible. Please format that mess of an exception properly, i.e. use the code formatting feature and preserver the line breaks exactly as they were.

Answer (score 1):

Don't declare Connection static, they will cause a collision in your stress tests or distributed environments, your final code that look like

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.itextpdf.text.log.LoggerFactory;

public class DAOConnectionFactory {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DAOConnectionFactory.class);
    private static final String databaseJNDI = "jdbc/presencedb";
    private static DataSource dataSource = null;
    private static Context context = null;
    private Connection conn = null;

    public DAOConnectionFactory() {
        System.out.println("Initialized");
    }

    static {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            try {
                context = new InitialContext();

                if (context == null) {
                    context = new InitialContext();
                }

                dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:comp/env/" + databaseJNDI);
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                logger.error("Error while creating datasource.", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Error while getting database connection.", e);
        }
        return conn;
    }

    protected static void closeConnection(Connection connection, Statement statement, ResultSet resultSet) {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error while closing resultset.", e);
            }
        }
        if (statement != null) {
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error while closing statement.", e);
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error while closing connection.", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the call like

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {

    public static String SQL_UPDATE = "query";

    public DAOConnectionFactory factory = new DAOConnectionFactory();

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Main instanceppl = new Main();
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        connection = instanceppl.factory.getConnection();
        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_UPDATE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        instanceppl.factory.closeConnection(connection, preparedStatement, null);

    }

}
```